# JTable will not auto resize last column

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have a JTable that is placed inside a JPanel which is then placed in a JFrame that has another JPanel that has a ScrollPane. The general idea can be seen below if the explanation is confusing. I have set my JTable to auto resize the last column, but it never auto sizes. What is the problem?

JFrame -> JPanel -> JTable 
-> JPanel -> Scroll Pane

My code: 
`this` refers to my class which extends `JFrame`

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JTextArea log = new JTextArea(20, 50);
log.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

String[] configRow = {"Config File", "Not Loaded"};
String[] logRow = {"Log File" , "Not Loaded"};
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
dtm.addColumn("");
dtm.addColumn("");
dtm.addRow(configRow);
dtm.addRow(logRow);

JTable status = new JTable(dtm);
status.setTableHeader(null);
status.setShowGrid(false);
status.setEnabled(false);
status.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);

JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
tablePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
tablePanel.add(status, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

JPanel logPanel = new JPanel();
logPanel.add(logScrollPane);

this.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.add(logPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: What behavior are you looking for here? Do you want the last column to get all of the extra space? If the frame is resized smaller, do you want only the last column to shrink?

Comment: the last column will load the full file path, so I want it to resize accordingly to that size

Comment: So you want the table to resize based on a change to its data in the model? I don't think `setAutoResizeMode` will help you here then. That is just resizing based on the user actually resizing the columns or the window containing the table. If you want the table to resize its columns when the data being displayed in the column changes, you will need to handle the resizing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your JTable must be placed inside a JScrollPane in order for the resizing to work properly. You are placing the JTable directly on a JPanel.

```
tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(status), BorderLayout.LINE_START):
```

Comment: My last column still didn't resize, and my panel just got bigger with extra unwanted space

Comment: That extra space can be fixed by calling `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize` on the table. Now that I've got your code running, I can see that my answer isn't the solution.